# Objects having same distance/radius from the center (camera) in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's a 360 Video application on Unity 3D.
I want to place several objects around the camera (which has a fixed position), but I need this objects to have the same distance (same radius) from the Camera (which is the center). How can I do this? Either on Editor or by code.

I have been manually displacing objects around the camera, by dragging them by arrow tool. But it's as inaccurate as a pain to do. :)

Any light on this would help me a lot! Not only me, but anyone working with 360 videos in Unity.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: With what are you struggling? 1) The Math behind getting the the object's position? or 2) The Coding part for setting the object's position?

Comment: Just a quick look at the API: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

Comment: I recommend having a parent at 0,0,0 and adding a child n distance from 0,0 and then rotating the parent around. This parent would be a child of the camera so that it follows the camera along. Quick and simple solution to your problem. I'm sure with math you could probably spawn them at said distance with a random angle but I don't feel the need for such math if it's not a massive project that requires optimization.

Also, since you said several objects around the camera, just duplicate the "parent" I first mentioned and rotate them all as you wish.

Comment: Alox, please make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, an easy solution would be to add a child "child_of_camera" to your camera and then add a child "child_of_child" to the "child_of_camera".

Now that you've done this, move the "child_of_child" away to however far from the camera you'd like it to be. After this, apply the random rotation you'd like to "child_of_camera".

Duplicate "child_of_camera" to however many objects you'd like on screen and then rotate them all to your preference.

Now, when you're moving around the camera, these children will follow along with the camera.

If you're looking so that the rotation of the camera doesn't affect the objects there are two ways you can handle this:

1. Place camera and "child_of_camera" (this name would now be misleading and should be renamed) under an empty GameObject and move "empty_GO" on the X,Y,Z axis instead of the camera.

or

2. Create a quick script to attach onto "child_of_camera" so that it always sets the "child_of_camera"s world space rotation to Vector3.zero.

As I stated in the comments, this solution is most likely not the optimal way to fix your problem but it is definitely a very simple solution that is easy to understand and implement. I hope it helps.